# getView method in android

Tags: android, mobile-phones

I watched some videos but i did not understand why we use `getView` method in custom adopter in android. Can anyone  explain that what does getView method do in array adopter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to read and watch more But nothing help better than testing.
getView() is getting view ;) 
*Getting Each Item* of Adapter to Access Each Elements.
For example you create ListView and set Custom Adapter.
and for each item in list you have some other child views.
Image of People (ImageVIew) and Name (TextView) & etc.
to access and modify each of these elements you call getView in Adapter Class.
Take look and test this Example: [Tutorial for Custom Adapter](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67)

modify  and destroy it to understand how it works. Good Luck

Comment: thank u dear
when does this method call??

Comment: Each time you set data to item. For example each  time time in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a `View`(the simple building block) and then you have `AdapterView` which takes some data and then fits the data at appropriate place.

Each `AdapterView` has a number of View object to fit the data. For example if you have a `ListView` to show the name each planet, then basically you have

Mercury     --->Row 1 to View object1

Venus       --->Row 2 to View object2

Earth       --->Row 3 to View object3

Mars        --->Row 4 to View object4

...         other rows

now if you want to know which item or row was clicked then you need to attach a listener to the `ListView` and then use the `getView()` method to know which row was clicked.

Comment: thank u for the explaination

Comment: when does this method call??

Comment: it is called when your row item is clicked.